# PHP 7.2 support patch

Tags: magento-1.9.3.10

Does M1 ver 1.9.3.10 already includes the PHP 7.2 support patch? I want to know if I still need to install the PHP 7.2 support patch after installing 1.9.3.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No version 1.9.3.10 doesn't contain patch for PHP 7.2. You need to install it.

You can see below statement at magento community forum.

```
Additionally, support for PHP 7.2 will be included as part of the Magento Commerce 1.14.4.0 and Magento Open Source 1.9.4.0 releases, which are currently scheduled for late 2018.
```

Here is [link](https://community.magento.com/t5/News-Announcements/PHP-7-2-Support-Patches-for-Magento-1-are-now-available/m-p/106999#M211) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you, so how come 1.9.3.10 is not included in the PHP 7.2 patch?  https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240

Comment: Not sure why. but you can see on same page https://magento.com/tech-resources/download They mention patch list included for 1.9.3.10 and PHP 7.2 patch is not there

Comment: I guess they just didn't update the documentation. In the link you sent me, it mentions that the last patch is also compatible with just released version 1.9.3.10. Thank you.